# How to set Subversion Anonymous Commit?

Tags: svn, configuration

In private use, I want to enable subversion commit without access, but

```
svnserve.conf
[general]
anon-access = write
```

It doesn't work at all.

```
svnserve.conf
[general]
anon-access = write
authz-db = authz

authz
* = rw
```

It also doesn't work.
Of couse I can set user and use. But is it impossible to enable anonymous commit ?

Comment: It's not impossible, but it's inadvisable. Why do you want to do this? How are you serving your repository, and are you certain that your configuration file is being used?

Comment: I just found out and I just want to know why. Seriously, no problem at all. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just after svnserve service shutdown and restart, it works.